# How to dismiss middle viewControllers and come back to rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have three view controllers, say root, middle, last. I want to go back from `lastViewController` to `rootViewController`.

I tried custom delegate and `NSNotificationCenter`. But while going back the `middleViewController` flashes for a second (it's `viewWillDisappear` gets called). 
I'm using `presentViewController`/`dismissViewController` and not navigation. I don't want that `middleViewController` getting flashed.

I have below code in rootViewCotroller:

`-(void)viewDidLoad {`

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(actionBackToRoot) name:@"BackToRoot" object:nil];`

`}`

`-(void)actionBackToRoot : (NSNotification *) notification{`

`NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;`

`UIViewController *lastViewController = [userInfo objectForKey:@"viewController"];`

`[middleViewController  dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

`[lastViewController  dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

`}`

On click of close button of lastViewController, code as below -

`[dict setValue:self forKey:@"viewController"];`

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"BackToRoot" object:nil userInfo:dict];`

Does anyone have solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your navigating code ..

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `lastViewController.navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true )`

Comment: OP is not using navigation controller.

Comment: OP ? So you don't want to go "back"

Comment: I'm not using navigation controller. Want to do this with dismissViewController.

Comment: so you should dismiss all non-top controller without animation.